# How to mask specific values in particular column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file with 5 columns and about 5000 rows. In a particular column called 'summary' in the .csv file there is credit card numbers along with a few text. It looks like this

> hey this job needs to be done asap and pay with card# visa 5611000043310001

I want to read this column, take out the number (maybe by using regular expression) and then mask the last 4 digits and  write out the entire row as it is with the masked number like this in a .csv file.

> hey this job needs to be done asap and pay with card# visa 561100004331****

How can I do it?

Comment: df['summary']=df['summary'].str[:-4]+'****' ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen I want to mask only the number..this line applies it to everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex, you could do:

```
import re

>> s = "hey this job needs to be done asap and pay with card# visa 5611000043310001"
>> re.sub(r"(\d{12})\d{4}",r"\1****",s)

'hey this job needs to be done asap and pay with card# visa 561100004331****'
```

So basically, `(\d{12})` matches the first 12 digits (the parentheses are there to not replace these first 12). And then 4 digits, that we replace by stars. `\1` is a placeholder for the first group that is omitted by the replacement, so here it refers to the first 12 digits.

Comment: Ohh nicee! How would I apply re.sub() to a panadas dataframe with many rows?

Comment: You would just need to do `df["summary"] = df["summary"].str.replace(r"(\d{12})\d{4}",r"\1****")`

Comment: Or also `df["summary"] = df["summary"].apply(lambda s: re.sub(r"(\d{12})\d{4}",r"\1****",s))`, both should work

Comment: Niceee. Thank you!

Comment: Hey this worked for numbers that had '1' as the last 5th digit. How to apply for others too?

Comment: What do you mean? For me it seems to work for any 16-digits numbers. Can you give me an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: I am sorry. I had made a mistake elsewhere that was affecting thing. Your solution worked correctly! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The replace function with regex below looks for numbers of exactly 16 digits and masks the last 4 digits.

So this code:

```
eg_summaries = [
    'blah blah card# visa 5611000043310001',
    'blah blah card# visa 5611000043310001 with text after',
    '5611000043310001',
    'visa: 5611000043310001 and random number > 16 digits: 0011237324763246723487243',
               ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'summary': eg_summaries })
df['summary'].replace(r'\b(\d{12})\d{4}\b', r'\1****', inplace=True, regex=True)
print (df.summary)
```

should print out this:

`0                                              blah blah card# visa 561100004331****
1                              blah blah card# visa 561100004331**** with text after
2                                                                   561100004331****
3    visa: 561100004331**** and random number > 16 digits: 0011237324763246723487243`

Comment: Coool! Thanks a lot